# Trying to read a barcode with an iPad

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner

From [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide):

I did the following:

```
$ cordova create hellobc1 com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
$ cd hellobc1
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova prepare
```

Then from [here](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/barcode), I did this:

$ cordova plugins add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git

Then I added this to the Index.html page:

```
<button id="startScan">Start Scan</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Then I added this to the Index.js page:

```
var resultDiv;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {
   document.querySelector("#startScan").addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
   resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
}

function startScan() {
   alert('startScan');
   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
   function (result) {
      var s = "Result: " + result.text + "<br/>" +
      "Format: " + result.format + "<br/>" +
      "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled;
      resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
   }, 
   function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
   });
}
```

The alert('startScan') popped up when I pressed the button, but the camera hasn't activated.
For some reason, I had to change the Index.html that was in staging/www if that provides any clues.

Comment: did you run `cordova prepare` again after installing the plugin?

Comment: Which phonegap version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cordova prepare again.